# Lost the back button React Native Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a problem with react native navigation bar. At the third screen("Auth" at stack navigator) back button I lost back button. How can I fix it?

I use this function for the navigate:

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate("Choose")
this.props.navigation.navigate("Auth")
```

Code of NavigationContainer:

```js
<View style={styles.container}>
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={Hello} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Choose" component={ChooseMessengers} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={Auth} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    <StatusBar style="auto" />
</View>
```

[image: First Screen]

[image: Second Screen]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To have the back button, you have to push screens on top of the stack.

```
this.props.navigation.push("Auth")
```

Comment: this should work.